# PopCap Framework

Tags: framework, графика, разработка-игр, c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать создание игр на PopCap. Нигде в инете не нашёл действительно полезной информации.

Answer (score 1):

С разбора [**примеров**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snakepopcap/).
Ну и [**сюда**](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/gdev/105011/) можно посмотреть.